# Toggle between useState using Switch from MUI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

trying to build my own Dark Mode for a specific component on my create-react-app site and using MUI. I have the Switch working to change the state on toggle but can't seem to find how to toggle it back and forth. Basically want to turn page dark on toggle and turn back to light on same toggle button. Suggestions please.

```
import React from 'react'
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';


const DarkMode = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color ? '#2c2d30' : '#ffffff' }}>
        <Switch onChange={setColor} />
        <h1 style={{ color: color ? '#ffffff' : '#000000' }}>Hello welcome to my site</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DarkMode
```

Comment: have you try this ```<Switch onChange={() => setColor(!color)} />```?

Comment: Amazing! Makes sense. How about if I want to take this further and use this same toggle to set dark mode for other components on different files? Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const DarkMode = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = React.useState(false)

    const toggle = () =>{
      setColor(!color);
    }
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color ? '#2c2d30' : '#ffffff' }}>
        <Switch onChange={toggle} />
        <h1 style={{ color: color ? '#ffffff' : '#000000' }}>He</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DarkMode
```

Comment: magical! Thanks so much, this solved my issue. Now taking this a step further. Any suggestions for using this same toggle to be able to access different components for this dark mode technique? That are on different files in my React app?

Comment: I see you are using MUI. For consistency, I would recommend you check the MUI document for the dark mode implementation: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/, If you really want to do it by yourself, you can set a global state using context and warp it around your <App />